# API in C# works fine with Postman but not from PureCloud

Tags: api, postman

I create an integration layer in .NET that sits between PureCLoud and BMC Remedy and this integration layer was developed in VS 2015. It was working fine with first deployment.

Now I added 5 new methods in API and when deployed it on Prod then old functionality stopped working. This time I used VS 2017. But deployed API's are returning expected data in Postman.